# How to map array with Python

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I have this Python code, I want to map the array of regex strings, to compiled regexes, and I need to create a function that checks to see if a certain line of texts matches all the given regular expressions. But I suck at Python and only know JS and Java.

```
#sys.argv[2] is a JSON stringified array

regexes = json.loads(sys.argv[2]);

#need to call this for each regex in regexes
pattern = re.compile(regex)

def matchesAll(line):
    return True if all line of text matches all regular expressions
```

In JS, what I want looks like:

```
// process.argv[2] is a JSON stringified array
var regexes = JSON.parse(process.argv[2])
                 .map(v => new RegExp(v))

function matchesAll(line){
     return regexes.every(r => r.test(line));
 }
```

Can somehow help me translate? I was reading about how to do mapping of arrays with Python and I was like huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compile all expressions you can simply use

```
patterns = map(re.compile, regexs)
```

and to do the check:

```
def matchesAll(line):
    return all(re.match(x, line) for x in patterns)
```

Comment: do I have to "import all"?

Comment: @AlexanderMills No. It's builtin function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
regexes = [re.compile(x) for x in json.loads(sys.argv[2])]

def matchesAll(line):
    return all([re.match(x, line) for x in regexes])
```

---

Test Example:

```
import re

regexes = [re.compile(x) for x in ['.*?a.*','.*?o.*','.*r?.*']]

def matchesAll(line):
    return all([re.match(x, line) for x in regexes])

print matchesAll('Hello World aaa')
print matchesAll('aaaaaaa')
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: thanks, I will move on to this, I will post an answer of what I have

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have, I hope it's right

```
regex = json.loads(sys.argv[2]);

regexes=[]

for r in regex:
    regexes.append(re.compile(r))

def matchesAll(line):
    for r in regexes:
        if not r.search(line):
            return False
    return True
```

I will try @MYGz's answer, the lambda syntax is pretty foreign to me.